# 3 Stones Problem (High School Physics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I couldn't figure out how to do this question:

3 stones of different mass (m, 2m, 3m) are thrown vertically upward with 3 different velocities (v, 2v, and 3v, respectively).  Rank from high to low the maximum height of each stone. air resistance is negligible.

Thanks,
-W

Comment: What is the shape of the stones?  Are they all the same shape?  And note - air resistance is proportional to the cross-sectional area of the stone, and it's proportional to the square of the velocity.

Comment: sorry, i missed typed the information.  Air resistance is negligible, i meant to ask which stone will go the highest.  The shape of them is not given, but if air resistance is negligible, then it shouldn't matter

Comment: Ask yourself about their initial kinetic energies, and their final potential energies.

Comment: This is a kinematic question, i'm supposed to solve it with a kinematic, not energy. Thank you for the suggestion, could you show me which kinematic i need to use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you should note here:

- the downward gravitational acceleration (acceleration due to gravity ) on object (in the absence (negligible) of air resistance) is independent of mass of the object as well as its shape. It is given by:
  $$ g_{planet} = \frac {M_{planet}}{R^2}$$
- maximum height attained by a object is proportional to the square of initial velocity.

Comment: thank you, got it!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am new to this :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, thank you all for your answers, I think i figured it out, but could you all confirm?

The maximum height of each rock will be when v=0, so if I use vf^2=vi^2+2a(yf-yi), I will get 0=vi^2 +2gh.  This would mean that mass is unimportant and that the height of each rock is solely dependent on vi, which would make the largest rock, which is given the greatest initial velocity, the one that goes the highest.

Thank you all <3,
-W

Comment: You REALLY need to spend time reading the book and working through example problems.  Physics is NOT about memorizing the answer ... it's about memorizing the concept, and the only way to do that is to spend a lot of time thinking about the material.

Comment: Will do.  Working through more problems right now

Comment: And note - I taught high school physics for 13 years, so my feedback is based on observation of students, not my "best guess".  Good luck.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the advice